# Minecraft Forge: Can the update emerald be activated by code?

Tags: minecraft-forge

You know that emerald icon that looks like the realms update icon? The one that appears when forge has an update? Does anyone know how to activate this with one's own mod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found it:
https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/autoupdate

P.S: Random words to go up to the limit.